# Retain select option value that are dependent on other select box - country state city

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form in which i display all countries from database, based on the the country selected state is populated and based on state, city is populated using jquery. Everything is working fine. Problem is when page is submitted and reloaded i am able to only retain country but not able to retain state and city select boxes as they get dynamically populated using onChange event fired with select option. Issue is under select boxes of state and city i do not do anything and hence when page reloads i do not get values entered by user. Any help on this is appreciated.

Following is the code

included in php -

```
<select name='country' onChange='selectCity(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)'>
<option value='%'>Select Country</option>"
.$searchController->CreateCSCValues($searchController->GetCSCCountries(),'country').
"</select>

<select name='state' id='state_dropdown' onChange='selectState(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)'>
<option value='%'>Select State</option>
</select>

<select name='city' id='city_dropdown'>
<option value='%'>Select City</option>
</select>
```

Javascript/jquery -------

```
function selectCity(country_id){
           loadData('state',country_id);..........}

function selectState(state_id){
                loadData('city',state_id);......... and then }

function loadData(loadType,loadId){
      var dataString = 'loadType='+ loadType +'&loadId='+ loadId;
src="image/loading.gif" />');
     $.ajax({D
     type: "POST",
     url: "get-State-City.php",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(result){
            $("#"+loadType+"_loader").hide();
            $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").append(result);
    }
});
```

in file get-State-City.php - loadtype and loadid are passed and depending on loadtype either state or city table is accessed and values displayed under state/city dropdown boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier then you think. Because your scripts only run on a onchange event, you can  prefill the dropboxes, and you don't even have to change anything to your javascripts. Example:

```
<select name='country' onChange='selectCity(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)'>
    <option value='%'>Select Country</option>
    <?php if( /* country is given */ ): ?>
        <?php foreach($countries as $country): ?>
            <?php $selected = $country->id == $selected_country_id ? ' selected="selected" : ''; ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $country->id; ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $country->name; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $searchController->CreateCSCValues($searchController->GetCSCCountries(),'country'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</select>

// the same for the other two dropdowns
```

Now everything is prefilled (if any value is given), and the onchange still works. easy does it! :)

Comment: Thanks giorgio. what you mentioned is already taken care in function CreateCSCValues and as i have no problem with country drop down as i am able to retain its value. Problem is with State and City drop down, these are getting populated using jquery during onchange event.

Comment: yw :) don't forget to accept the answer if it really helped you (and is indeed the answer you were looking for). And stay tuned on SO, try to help others with your own knowledge if you are able to!